Topological Sorting question. Does the values of an edge impact the order in which they are sorted?
I am currently working on the "Longest Road" Dag problem, and finished writing my topological sorting algorithm in Java. Currently I am using edges with no value associated to them, and I am wondering how this affects the sorting method.
For example, if I have a Very simple dag with the following edges:
(A-B),(A-C),(C-D),(C-E),(F-E)
Sorting these Topologically would give me something that looks like this:
(B,D,E,C,A,F) (if im not mistaken).
Now, if I were to swap the order of the initial pairings, but keep them the same, e.g.
(A-C),(A-B),(C-E),(C-D),(F-E)
The topological sort would then look something like:
(E,D,C,B,A,F), which would change the sorting even though the graph remains unchanged.
First question: Does this phenomenon impact the usage of the topological sort?
Now, if you were to replace these would Values, instead of (A-B), it would be (100) and (A-C) would be (25), representing perhaps a distance, is it necessary to check a lower or higher value first when trying to see the distance on a "route"?
Thanks for answers in advance.
I haven't implemented any distance in my code yet, just want to make sure I understand the scenario I'm working with.

The question is not related to Java so the Java tag is not correct.

This phenomenon does not negatively impact the usage of topological sort in general since any valid topological order is usually acceptable.

Topological sorting isn't related to distance.
